# How Setup Parameters for AddHttpClient when IHttpClientFactory is created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I'm try setting up a `IHttpClientFactory`, and i'd like to know how to send it parameters when it is created, those parameters i need to assign to retry policy.

I'm using .Net Core 2.2 and Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly, I've read [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

I have this is Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://interface.net");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
})
.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(p => p.WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600)));
```

I used it in this way

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _iHttpClientFactory;

public ValuesController(IHttpClientFactory iHttpClientFactory)
{
    _iHttpClientFactory = iHttpClientFactory;
}

public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
{
    var client = _iHttpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient");
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/Service?Id=123");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to send parameters when i execute the `CreateClient`, for assign to `retryCount` and `sleepDuration` in the `AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy`, in this case 3 and 600 respectively, because i need to create clients with different `retryCounts` and `sleepDurations` and those values can change.

Something like this

```
var retryCount = 5;
var sleepDuration = 400;
var client = _iHttpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient", retryCount, sleepDuration);
```

Or another way?

Comment: Latest (.net 6) how-to at [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 8):

As far as I am aware, you cannot. That's not really how `IHttpClientFactory` is designed to work. The idea is having reusable clients for specific scenarios, not an infinitely configurable client to be shared across different scenarios, and the Polly config pretty much goes along with that.

In other words, the design is that you'd configure a client or clients with the various retry policies and such you want, and then you'd specify which of those you want for a particular scenario.

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://interface.net");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
})
.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(p => p.WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600)));

services.AddHttpClient("MyClient2", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://interface.net");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
})
.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(p => p.WaitAndRetryAsync(5, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400)));
```

Then, you could call `CreateClient` with either `"MyClient"` or `"MyClient2"`. To keep from repeating yourself with the main client config, you could either factor out the body:

```
Action<HttpClient> myClientConfig = c =>
{
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", myClientConfig);
```

Or, you might consider creating a custom extension:

```
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddMyClient(this IServiceCollection services, string clientName)
{
    return services.AddHttpClient(clientName, c =>
    {
        ...
    });
}
```

And then:

```
services.AddMyClient("MyClient")
    .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(...);
```

In general, though, the Polly policies should pretty much be bound to a particular use case. You'll know what the particular API/endpoint needs and you'll build a policy directly around that. A different API/endpoint may need different handling, but that's an argument for a different client in such a case.

Comment: Ok, i wanted to avoid that but if there is no other way, i will have to do it. Thanks for your time

Comment: The point is that this is likely a design problem on your part. There shouldn't be a need to have different policies for a particular client configuration. If there's that much difference between various endpoints on the API or whatever, then that validates having multiple different clients customized for each scenario.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. It was not a design problem, it was a business request. My service will consume one API, i can't modify that API. Other services will consume the service that i make and they want to send me the amount of retry counts and sleep duration, because those services have different timeouts and responses time. For now, i use you suggest, i configured client for every service, even one without retry policy and i get values ​​from environment vars so they are easy to change

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify the `retryCount` and `sleepDuration` at the usage of `HttpClient` then you can do that through the `HttpRequestMessage` with the help of Polly's `Context`.

#### Define helpers

In order to easy the usage of `Context` (which is a `Dictionary<string, object>` under the hood) lets define some extension methods

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    private const string RetryCountKey = "RetryCount";
    private const string SleepDurationKey = "SleepDuration";

    public static Context WithRetryCount(this Context context, int retryCount)
    {
        context[RetryCountKey] = retryCount;
        return context;
    }

    public static Context WithSleepDuration(this Context context, TimeSpan sleepDuration)
    {
        context[SleepDurationKey] = sleepDuration;
        return context;
    }

    public static int? GetRetryCount(this Context context)
        => context[RetryCountKey] as int?;

    public static TimeSpan? GetSleepDuration(this Context context)
        => context[RetryCountKey] as TimeSpan?;
}
```

#### Register a named client

The `AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy` does not have an overload which allow us to access the `HttpRequestMessage` so, we have to switch back to `AddPolicyHandler`

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://httpstat.us/");
    //...
})
.AddPolicyHandler((_, request) =>
{
    var context = request.GetPolicyExecutionContext();
    return HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
      .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        context.GetRetryCount() ?? 3,
        _ => context.GetSleepDuration() ?? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300),
        onRetry: (_, __) => Console.WriteLine("Retry is triggered"));
});
```

- We can retrieve the `Context` via the `GetPolicyExecutionContext` method of the `HttpRequestMessage`
- Because the `GetRetryCount` and `GetSleepDuration` might return `null` that's why we can define here some fallback values
- *I've specified an `onRetry` just for debugging purposes*

#### Provide parameters at usage

As you have already guessed it there is a `SetPolicyExecutionContext` method as well on the `HttpRequestMessage`

```
private readonly HttpClient client;
public XYZController(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
    client = factory.CreateClient("MyClient");
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> Get()
{
    var context = new Context()
         .WithRetryCount(5)
         .WithSleepDuration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/408");
    request.SetPolicyExecutionContext(context);
    
    _ = await client.SendAsync(request);
    return "...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement where I had to retrieve the client lifetime from an API in the setup phase, which also returned an authentication token that I need in the setup method. I solved it with a custom extension method:

```
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddHttpClientWithCustomLifetime<TClient, TImplementation>(
    this IServiceCollection services, Func<(TimeSpan, string)> authenticationFunc, Func<string, Action<HttpClient>> configureClient)
    where TClient : class where TImplementation : class, TClient
{
    var (lifetime, authToken) = authenticationFunc();
    return services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(configureClient(authToken)).SetHandlerLifetime(lifetime);
}
```

This first calls some function that returns the lifetime and authentication token. The token is then passed into the actual config function, and the lifetime is used in the `SetHandlerLifetime` function.

I call it like this in Startup:

```
(TimeSpan, string) ConfigureLifetimeAsync(IntegrationConfiguration config)
{
    var result = AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () =>
    {
        using var authClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(config.AuthUrl, UriKind.Absolute) };
        var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            // ...
        };
        return await authClient.PostAsync<OAuthTokenResponse>(string.Empty, parameters, new SerilogLoggerFactory(Log.Logger).CreateLogger<ILogger<Integration>>());
    });
    return (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(result.Result.ExpiresIn)), result.Result.AccessToken);
}
services.AddHttpClientWithCustomLifetime<IIntegration, Integration>(() => ConfigureLifetimeAsync(config), authToken => c =>
{
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {authToken}");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Api-Key", config.ApiKey);
});
```